# CSS grid, Day.js : How do I create a calendar that shows the current week's dates?

Tags: reactjs, css-grid, dayjs

Within a react component, I'd like to create a grid calendar showing showing the current week's dates. So for this week for example, it would need to look something like this:

```
Monday          | Tuesday         |Wednesday       |        
October 5th 2020| October 6th 2020|October 7th 2020|
```

I've had a play around with day.js to try and solve this, but it's proven tricky. Here's my attempt in codesanbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-rgb-me4s3?file=/src/App.js

Any suggestions on how to approach this? I'm not sure how to set the beginning of each grid to the monday of a given week - once I've done that, I can figure out the logic to do the other days.

Here's the code:

`Grid component`

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

export default App = () => {

  let now = dayjs()
  let currentDay = (now.format("dddd, MMMM D YYYY"))

  let d = now.add('1', 'day')
  let nextDay = (d.format("dddd, MMMM D YYYY"))
  
  return(
    <div className = 'grid-container'>
      <div className = 'grid-item'>{currentDay}</div>
      <div className = 'grid-item'>{nextDay}</div>
      <div className = 'grid-item'></div>
      <div className = 'grid-item'></div>
      <div className = 'grid-item'></div>
      <div className = 'grid-item'></div>
      <div className = 'grid-item'></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`styles.css`

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-row-gap:1px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: blue;
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: Have you saved the changes to the codesandbox because it's just containing the default boilerplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`startOf('week')`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/start-of) to get the first day of the current week and then construct an array of all 7 days of that week to render it:

```
export default () => {
  const startOfWeek = dayjs().startOf("week");

  const weekdays = new Array(7).fill(startOfWeek).map(
    (day, idx) => day.add(idx, "day").format("dddd, MMMM D YYYY")
  );

  return (
    <div className="grid-container">
      {weekdays.map((day) => (
        <div key={day} className="grid-item">
          {day}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit delicate-wind-mp1tg]

Depending on the locale the start of the week may vary. You can configure the start of a week to be monday by [setting it in the locale](https://day.js.org/docs/en/customization/customization):

```
import en from "dayjs/locale/en";

dayjs.locale({
  ...en,
  weekStart: 1
});
```

If you don't want to modify the locale you can also use [`day(1)`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/get-set/day) to get the monday of the current week:

```
const startOfWeek = dayjs().day(1); // will be the monday of the current week with the default locale
```

Comment: Brilliant answer - much appreciated. Could I ask you another question related to the grid I'm trying to create?

Comment: @JoshSimon Sure, you can ask. You can also make it a new SO question and pass me the link if it requires some context.

Comment: thanks - here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217562/css-grid-day-js-react-in-my-grid-based-calendar-how-do-i-push-grid-items-wit